# What font is used on this material design arabic RTL?

Tags: font-identification, google-material-design, arabic

I want create design in arabic RTL with material design like this :

[image: arabic material design]

I found that image in guideliness: https://material.google.com/style/writing.html

**what arabic font is used on that picture ?**

I have try automatic identification font service like "whatfontis", "whatthefont" but no result.
I try use Noto arabic font but not same like image.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is plain old Adobe Arabic. It is included with Adobe products, and is the default in Illustrator when Arabic characters are pasted or typed into a document. Looks like you can also purchase it here: https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/adobe/adobe-arabic

[image]

Comment: Finally, after waiting nearly a month.
Awesome, i think i will never found correct answer ...
thank you very much @Vicki

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `Noto Kufi Arabic` font:

[image]

It can be downloaded here: https://www.google.com/get/noto/#kufi-arab

Comment: Do you have any hints for the OP why this font is the correct one? They claim "I try use Noto arabic font but not same like image.", maybe you can show that this font can produce identical images?

Comment: `noto kufi arabic` is not same with the image. check this for difference: [noto kufi arabic](http://i.imgur.com/IW0NVu0.png)

Comment: it doesn't look at all like the font in the question

Comment: I am so curious to know which font is in the picture?